# Sum of prime remainders is greater than prime p

Tags: prime-numbers

This something like Waring meets the primes.  Take some prime p(n) and divide it by all the primes less than one-half p(n) to find the sum of the remainders that are themselves also primes.  Is there  some sum of these remainders for p(s1) that is greater than p(n) for all subsequent primes greater than p(n)?  Is there some p(s2) such than all primes greater than p(s2) will have a sum of remainders twice
p(s2)?  Some p(s3) for three times the sum of all its prime remainders for all primes greater than p(s3)?  This could be continued for some p(s4), [p(s5)...  Do you know if anyone has investigated this?

Comment: Could you please format your question a little bit, using different paragraphs, clear notations and MathJax? Currently very difficult to read.

Comment: just so I understand, for 31 (n=12?), the sum of remainders of division by primes less than 15.5 is 20. and 31>20 so s1>12 yes?

Comment: for 37 (n=13?) one of the remainders is 4 so you leave that out of the sum, correct?

Comment: For 31, 31mod2=1, 31mod3=1, 31mod5=1, 31mod7=3, 31mod11=9, 31mod13=5--->add only the primes 3 and 5 to get 8.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a
totally heuristic
non-rigorous attempt.

For a prime $p$,
there are about
$n =\dfrac{p}{2 \ln p}$
primes less than $p/2$.

For each of these primes,
say $q$,
the probability of 
the remainder being prime
is about $\dfrac{1}{\ln q}$.

Therefore the sum of these remainders
is about
$\sum_{q < p/2} \dfrac{q}{\ln q}
\sim \left(\dfrac{p}{2\ln p}\right)^2
$.

This is larger than $p$
by a factor of
$\dfrac{p}{(2\ln p)^2}$
which is greater than $1$,
so the sum is usually much
greater than $p$.

Comment: You can test the truth of what you contend by finding p(s1), p(s2) and a few others just to see how long it takes.  You'd have to go a   bit beyond your first answer to insure than no exceptional prime does not meet the requirement of having the sum of its prime remainders LESS than what is required; then you'd need a higher value in p(s1) or p(s2).

Comment: For 17 divide by 3 to get rem=2; divide by 5  to get rem=2; divide by 7 to get rem=3-->2+2+3=7 and less than 17.

Comment: It seems that your readers enjoy Grand Theory but do not bother to do the simple thing of testing if it is valid by doing some numerical examples by way of experimentation.  Whatever happened to empiricism?